# get content from other page generated by javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dom, file-get-contents

I got a situation where I want to get the content from another page which generates an image dynamicly by its parameters.

So for example I do got **test.php?u=user1&type=test**.
Opening this page will give me an **base64 encoded image SOURCE** inside the **div with id "test"** with an innerHTML.

The following code must do the job.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;

$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$doc->recover = true;

$doc->loadHTMLFile('test.php?u=user1&type=test');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$query = "//div[@id='test']";

$entries = $xpath->query($query);
var_dump($entries->item(0)->textContent);
```

Then my var_dump is returning nothing untill I litteraly put some text inside the div "test" on the other page.

How to get the dynamic text in my var_dump so I can use it on the other page?

Comment: You'll need a full headless browser, not just DOMDocument. Nothing in the above is going to *run* the JavaScript in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dynamic creation is made by JavaScript, you have to do this at a client pc. You can't run/render anything with JS inside php.

Solution:

- show the page
- wait for input
- send input data with ajax call to server
- other page polls data via ajax

Comment: The problem is that the image creation is indead done by a JavaScript, library, Google Chart. I have to setup an user backend and they may not see the the request URL within an Iframe or Ajax reuquest. So they can change it into another userId and see their chart. So I thought to get the base 64 image from another page and then put it in the image source on in the dashboard. Then je JSON array and javascript is not visable in that page, neither the request URL. I am encrypting the userId in the URL so if you can tell me what you tryed to achieve with your iframe it may be a solution.

Comment: If I understand you right: You have worries about the userid inside the sourcecode at client side, right?

Comment: Yes. I need to generate a chart with personal information. so I thought generation the image in another file with an ecrypted userid in the request must be most suitable and then the PHP can decrypt it and use it inside the query wich in generation the JSON data for the Google Chart.

Comment: Store the userId inside the session -> No user will ever see the userid and he couldn't guess other userids

Comment: 1. request main page from server

2. create random token

3. save token and timestamp into Database

4. create hompage with token and hidden IFrame readable with JS

5. User input data

6. update hidden iframe with a url containing the token

7. check timestamp of token and remove the token from database if everything is ok
8. create all data for iframe with php
9. render data inside iframe
10. get data out of iframe via jQuery
11. clear the iframe content